# Just Previous/Next 10 results Php Pagination

Tags: php, pagination

I have written a Pagination function, but have been struggling to add 'Previous' and 'Next' buttons. Any help or guidance would be most appreciated, I have had a look online and so far haven't been able to come up with an elegant solution.

```
$result = is database query results.

$per_page = 5;
if($result->num_rows != 0)
{
  $total_results = $result->num_rows;
  $total_pages = ceil($total_results / $per_page);
  if(isset($_GET['page']) && is_numeric($_GET['page']))
  {

    $show_page = $_GET['page'];

    if ($show_page > 0 && $show_page <= $total_pages)
    {
      $start = ($show_page -1) * $per_page;
      $end = $start + $per_page; 
    }
else
{
  $start = 0;
  $end = $per_page; 
}
else
{
 $start = 0;
 $end = $per_page;
}

$pag = '';

for ($i = $start; $i < $end; $i++)
{
// Make sure PHP doesnt show results that do not exist
if ($i == $total_results) { break; }
// Find Specific Row
$result->data_seek($i);
$row = $result->fetch_row();

// label Rows 
$id = $row[0];

    //USE AND DISPLAY RESULTS

    //Pagination
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $total_pages; $i++)
{       
   if($total_pages != 1)
   {
      if(isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] == $i)
      {
        $pag .= $i ." ";
      }
      else
      {
        $pag .= "<a href='index.php?page=$i'>$i</a>";
      }
   }
    }
}
else
{
 $pag .= 'no results';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already know the page you're on:

```
$_GET['page']
```

And the total pages:

```
$total_pages
```

So you could use that to get next and previous.

```
$page = 1;
if(isset($_GET['page']))
    $page = $_GET['page'];

$prev = $page - 1;
if($prev >= 1)
    $pag = "<a href='index.php?page=$prev'>Prev</a>";

for ($i = 1; $i <= $total_pages; $i++)
{       
   if($total_pages != 1)
   {
      if($page == $i)
      {
        $pag .= $i ." ";
      }
      else
      {
        $pag .= "<a href='index.php?page=$i'>$i</a>";
      }
   }
    }
}

$next = $page + 1;
if($next <= $total_pages)
    $pag .= "<a href='index.php?page=$next'>Next</a>";
```

Comment: Sorry, left off the =. Updated now. It should be $prev >= 1 so it will only display for pages greater than 1

Comment: I noticed that one, but still does not show... Also if the page is on index.php the next button has to be pressed twice, in order to get the index.php?page=2 to get the next set of results.

Comment: Try now. chances are you were trying without having $page defined. By default page + 1 probably resulted in 1, making your initial click seem redundant. I updated fully, so review it closely. Also, $prev is not supposed to show on page 1. Next is not supposed to show on the last page either.

Comment: This breaks, When clicking on next, no results appear... Although the Prev button does appear...

Comment: You sure you updated all instances of $_GET['page'] with $page? The bigger question is whether or not you're reading the logic here. Blindly, we may not give you the most perfect copy / paste example. It's often the principal that is important. If you look at the example, there are many holes that could be defined by user preference, but as a foundation it is a reasonable start. I would examine the code and tailor it until it does what you want.

Comment: Hi Kai, thanks for your help. I tweak bits of the code here and there and what was breaking it was in fact having '=' instead of '.=' for the previous button. An easy mistake to make when spending a large amount of time in front of a computer. Accepted your answer, thanks buddy.

Answer (score 0):

Sorta like this?

```
<a href="index.php?page=<?php echo ($_GET['page'] + 1); ?>">Next</a>
```